# React Transition Group: how do you unmount a component after it has finished it's exit animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

For example, for a modal, it should mount immediately and animate it's opacity to 1, but when a user exits out of the modal, it should animate it's opacity to 0, and then delay it's umount until the exit animation is finished.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and this is a ready at model in react-bootstrap model you can use it

use this link and you will find what you want exactly

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals

Comment: Could you please check the link? It doesn't work anymore